# PHP Warning: ldap_mod_add(): Modify: Object class violation in

Tags: php, ldap

I am trying to add ldap object attribute in php. But iam facing below error:

```
PHP Warning:  ldap_mod_add(): Modify: Object class violation in
```

Iam just trying to add attribute as below:

```
ldap_mod_add($conn,$dn,$my_attr);
```

I already searched in google, but still none of the answers didnt worked for me. This error seems to be an irritating since it doesnt clearly specify the actual problem.

Could anyone please tell me what could be the main issue of above error?

Comment: Are there not 3 parameters to that function? [The Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-mod-add.php)

Comment: @RiggsFolly : ya its 3 parameters.. before it was typo mistake.. now I edited.. Do you know any idea of above error?

Comment: Object class violation usually means you are trying to add an attribute to an object whose class does not define such attribute in the LDAP schema. Could you provide the object class of the object you are trying to modify, the attribute you are trying to add and the new value? Maybe the attribute is not multi-valued?